# Как получить картинку из API(Python)

Tags: python

Есть api PlaceGOAT(https://placegoat.com)
Как сохранить картинку из этого api с помощью модуля requests?

пробовал так

```
response=requests.get('https://placegoat.com/200/200')
with io.open('image.jpg', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(res.content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://placegoat.com/200/200')
img_file = open('photo.png', 'wb')
img_file.write(response.content)
img_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Заменить `io.open()` на `open()`
И передать в него картинку, в вашем случае `response.content`, а не `res.content`.

Попробуйте писать код в редакторе, который подсвечивает ошибки.